# JMeter request using JSR223 - 0 and empty response instead of real values

Tags: jmeter, listener, response, performance-testing, jsr223

Request in JSR223 Sampler works correctly, but here are Sampler result and Response data with 0 and empty values:
[image: View Results Tree - JSR223 Sampler - Sampler result]

[image]

Metrics in Sample result in red rectangle are equal to 0.
No response data (both headers and body) are available to see.

Is it possible to get somehow real numbers instead of 0 0 0 0 0 0 for metrics in Sampler result tab and to have visible response in Response data tab?

JSR223 Sampler code:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [reference documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), you can call those methods:

```
 SampleResult.connectEnd();
 SampleResult.latencyEnd();
 SampleResult.sampleEnd();
 SampleResult.setResponseData(driver.getPageSource(), "UTF-8");
```

You can use SampleResult [javadocs](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) to see all method or subclasses or custom class of yours.

**Note SampleResult is a variable name that JMeter binds into element, not the class**, so:

- don't prefix it with org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult, just use SampleResult
- don't import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult

Edit (after you added your JSR223 Sampler code):

To fill latency and connect time, use:

- SampleResult.setConnectTime()
- SampleResult.setLatency()

As you can get values from [Webdriver#executeScript()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) using such code that exploits [Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming):

```
long pageLoadTime= (Long)js1.executeScript("return (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd-window.performance.timing.responseStart)");
long latency= (Long)js1.executeScript("return (window.performance.timing.responseStart-window.performance.timing.navigationStart)");
long endtoEndRespTime= (Long)js1.executeScript("return (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart)");
long connectTime= (Long)js1.executeScript("return (window.performance.timing.connectEnd -window.performance.timing.connectStart)");
```

Comment: UBIK LOAD PACK, thank you. 
Is it possible to ask you to show a piece of groovy code in JSR223 with these methods?
Even I have 
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult; 
when I'm trying to use SampleResult, I have set of different error mesages, for example:
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

What I'm missing?

Comment: Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setResponseData() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [Response Data, UTF-8]
Possible solutions: setResponseData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), setResponseData(java.lang.String), getResponseData(), setResponseData([B), setResponseOK(), setResponseCode(java.lang.String).

Comment: what version of JMeter are you using ? Can you show your JSR223 Sampler code ? Are you using Groovy as language ?

Comment: JMeter 5.2.1. Yes, JSR223+groovy.

Comment: I am using the same version and it works fine for me. So can you show your sampler content please ? Thanks. I update my answer I suspect you're using full class name

Comment: Please see the screenshot, I added it to post.

Comment: Ok, remove the import of org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult

Comment: Thank you.
Now it shows in Sampler result tab more info:
Thread Name:Client-Side Thread Group - mobile 1-1
Sample Start:2020-09-03 11:17:08 UTC
Load time:4527
Connect Time:4526
Latency:4526
Size in bytes:13
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:13
Sample Count:1
Error Count:0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:200
Response message:OK.


But I stil have empty Response data (empty Response Headers and words "Response Data" in Response Body tab). How is it possible to see real response and response size?

Comment: replace the text "Response data" by what you get from driver, so  SampleResult.setResponseData(driver.getText(), "UTF-8"); If answer is ok , please accept  it also by checking the checkbox on the left of answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect time and latency - you need to get it from the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) using [WebDriver.executeScript()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) function, once done you can use `SampleResult.setConnectTime()` and `SampleResult.setLatency()`
2. Response can be obtained using [WebDriver.getPageSource()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) function so you should be able to do something like:

   ```
   SampleResult.setResponseData(driver.getPageSource())
   SampleResult.setBytes(driver.getPageSource().length())
   ```
3. Remove import of `org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult` as it comes as a [pre-defined shortcut](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)